# I cant browse php pages in my local server

Tags: php

I cant browse php pages in my local server.Before it was working fine. But now i cant browse php pages, i can browse html pages and asp pages , no problems with that.

But when i try to browse a php page its not loading.

What will be the problem??

I am using windows 2000 advanced server and my web server is Tomcat

please someone help me

Guys i'm not getting anything in my browser, its just continue to loading

Nothing showing in that page

i'm not getting any 404 error or anything like that. its just continue to be loading

for example consider my file is located under insider a folder named as myproject

i can reach upto this

http://localhost/projects/myproject

but after that i cant browse php pages inside that...

http://localhost/projects/myproject/index.php

this will continue to be loading, and nothing shows in that page

Comment: something got broken

Comment: my car doesn't move. but it was ok yesterday. Can you tell me please, what is broken and how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: We're going to need a little more information than that I'm afraid.

Comment: 1+ for the quick comment. @tibin mathew you will have to provide us with more details.

Comment: Are you getting 404? 503? or what?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it is just the php file you are testing?

Write a simple php file:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World?';
?>
```

Store it in a folder that you can access on your localhost like in htdocs/index.php or similiar.
Check if you can see it.

Comment: True, if error reporting is off and there is a fatal error in the PHP, it will just show a blank page and "not load"

Answer (score 0):

sound like you need to install php in your system.

Comment: uhh... what's with the rage?

Comment: Are the grayed out users from StackOverflow.com and that is why they are gray?
Seems like they may be disabled accounts. Could get confusing....

Answer (score 0):

The fact that tomcat can run asp is really interesting. My hunch is if asp pages are working, then probably your IIS is taking care of the requests instead of Tomcat. And you should be focusing on IIS PHP configuration instead of Tomcat configuration.

Comment: I don't think Tomcat is involved at all, why run PHP under Tomcat when you can run it directly under IIS?

Comment: Exactly .. the details provided include "I am using windows 2000 advanced server and my web server is Tomcat" .. so something doesn't add up there correctly.